How to deploy models to Power BI Embedded workspace
I tried to use Visual Studio to connect to the AAS model and change the deployment node to the Workspace connection of Power BI Embedded. However, during deployment, it prompted: Please contact a capacity administrator to make sure that MLA read/write support is enabled in the capacity settings on the Power BI Premium capacity, and then try again. I was able to deploy normally in this way when deploying to the workspace of Power BI Premium, but Power BI Embedded failed and I couldn't find any settings for XMAL read/write. Is it because the workspace of Power BI Embedded does not support deployment through Visual Studio or tabular editor?
Change deployment server to power bi embedded workspace
Error information
I hope to replace the AAS model with a dataset model, but I do not want to reconstruct each indicator in the AAS model one by one in the dataset model. I know there is a one click migration feature for Power BI Premium, but how about Power BI Embedded?
